# Java GUI - SwingWorker and gif

Tags: gif, swingworker

Ok so I am doing some taks of parsing data from document in SwingWorker which takes quite good amount of time.
And I am showing "loading gif" as JButton icon while doing this and also updating label every 15% done.
Its working ,but only problem is that gif is moving slowly or sometiems stop for sec and then start again. GIF is basically not animating smooth.
JButton is disabled and I set this gift as icon for disabled JButton.

In MainGUI class:

```
jButton3.setDisabledIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/loading.gif")));
```

After user click on button I call this:

```
        runLoader=new CashLoader(jButton3, jLabel2, ucty, userLock);
        jButton3.setEnabled(false);
        jLabel2.setForeground(Color.GRAY);
        executor.execute(runLoader);
```

CashLoader thread do this:

```
 @Override
    protected Object doInBackground() {
      // long code is here
      // somewhere in the code I call evey 15% done this:
      publish(new PublishingClass(sum, true));
    }

@Override
protected void process(List<PublishingClass> sum){
    for (PublishingClass publishingThing : sum) {
        if (publishingThing .isOrangeColor()) lblSum.setForeground(new Color(226,182,3));
        lblSum.setText(""+publishingThing .getNumber()+" %");
    }
}

@Override
protected void done(){
    btnReload.setEnabled(true);
   ...
}
```

Thats sorter version of code. As you can see I am not doing anything in SwingWorker doInBackground() method with JButton. Once its set to disabled it should show gif as its icon. Which is obviously doing ,but not smooth ,it just stops for few seconds or once I move with mouse over window then it starts moving gif . It basicly shows laggy gif.

Comment: sounds like you need to move your data parsing to a separate thread, right now it sounds like you're doing that on the ui thread

Comment: No I am doing it in SwingWorker doInBackground method.

Comment: Just wondering if I should call more often publish method in doInBackground or there is other problem

Comment: -1 for not showing any code and wasting everyone's time

Comment: Code has over 1000 lines .. thats quiet big .. I will try to take out some little sum up ..